# Enum associative array with choose from list in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

In my example below, I'm trying to `say` the colour of the selected fruit in the `choose from list` menu, but I cannot figure out how to get the colour associated with the fruit.

```
set fruitList to {"apple", "orange", "blueberry"}
set fruitColor to {apple:"red", orange:"orange", blueberry:"blue"}
set fruitListItem to {choose from list fruitList}
if fruitListItem is not false then
    set fruit to get fruitColor of fruitListItem
    say fruitColor
    say fruitListItem
end if
```

I get the error *Can’t get fruitColor of {{"apple"}}.* after pressing Ok on a fruit in the list. [Kaydell's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99094/34929) on AD seems very close to what I want but I don't understand how to use `get` in my example. In Swift or PHP you might do something like `foo['bar']` for example.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues beside the dictionary/record problem.

- Remove the enclosing braces around `choose from list fruitList` otherwise the result is a nested list.
- `choose from list` returns always a list – even if `multiple selections` is disabled – or `false` if the user presses `Cancel`. You have to flatten the list with `item 1 of`

The keys of AppleScript records are labels like variables, not strings. The labels are evaluated at compile time. A record cannot be subscripted by a string.

A workaround is to create an `NSDictionary` from the record where the key labels are converted to strings.

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set fruitList to {"apple", "orange", "blueberry"}
set fruitColors to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:{apple:"red", orange:"orange", blueberry:"blue"}
set fruitListItem to choose from list fruitList
if fruitListItem is not false then
    set fruit to item 1 of fruitListItem
    set fruitColor to (fruitColors's objectForKey:fruit) as text
    say fruitColor
    say fruitListItem
end if
```

This is an example with a nested dictionary

```
set userNames to {"John", "Jane"}
set users to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:{John:{name:"John Smith", age:25}, Jane:{name:"Jane Smith", age:30}}
set chosenName to choose from list userNames
if chosenName is not false then
    set userName to item 1 of chosenName
    set currentUser to users's objectForKey:userName
    set userAge to (currentUser's objectForKey:"age") as integer
    say userName
    say (userAge as text)
end if
```

Comment: That looks neat, thank you. I got a follow up though- if I want to have multiple properties I'm thinking it would first go something like this? `set user to current application's [...]:{John:{name:"John Smith", age:25}, Jane:{name:{Jane Smith", age:30}}` how would I (in the your example `say` John and Jane's name and age?

Comment: You have to call `objectForKey` twice. First to get the inner dictionary and then to get `name` and `age`.

Comment: Something like: `set contact to item 1 of contactListItem
set userName to (user's objectForKey:contact) as text
set userAge to )user's objectForKey:contact) as text`

Comment: Almost. `set contact to item 1 of contactListItem set user to (contact's objectForKey:"John")  set userAge to (user's objectForKey:"age") as integer`

Comment: In that last part, I can't see how the `objectForKey` knows what user age to look up.

Comment: The user is specified by the first `objectForKey`. Each pair of braces represents an *object*.

Comment: I missed the bit where you changed it from `contact's` to `user's`. Could you please show how you'd do that with the 2 properties name and age inside the John object? Does that mean I'd do `objectForKey` 3 times all up?

Comment: I get an error *"NSDictionary doesn’t understand the “dictionaryWithDictionary_” message."*. What about instead of using NSDictionary could do something like `set users to {John:"John Smith", age:25, uid:555}
say age of users` but I don't know how to do it for John and Jane.

Comment: You have to include always the `use` headers if AppleScriptObjC is involved. And if the labels are hard-coded you don't need NSDictionary for example `set users to {John:{name:"John Smith", age:25}, Jane:{name:"Jane Smith", age:30}}
say age of users's John`